# Getting ADB screen mirroring to work on Android14 beta QPR3

Tags: mirroring, android-14, screencast

I am on a Pixel8 and using Android14 beta QPR3. I want to use **ADB screen mirroring** on it. I was trying many ADB screen mirroring options like Vysor, SCRCPY and droidAtJar but none worked.
Before updating to beta it worked on stable Android14 version

The objective is to get ADB screen mirroring to work on Android14 QPR3 beta on Pixel8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these issues and a fix in the comments:

- https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/pull/4656
- https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/pull/4657

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Issue is sorted